# HTML form validation with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

im a bit new using javascript in HTML. I want to validate a HTML script using javascript however what i've written doesn't seem to work. Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong???
Here is the Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function mandatoryFields()
{
var x=document.forms["add"]["contract_id"].value
if (x==null || x=="")
  {
  alert("Please Enter the Contract Title");
  return false;
  }
var x=document.forms["add"]["storydiv"].value
if (x==null || x=="")
  {
  alert("Please Enter a Sprint");
  return false;
  }
var x=document.forms["add"]["storydiv"].value
if (x==null || x=="")
  { 
  alert("Please Enter a Story");
  return false
  }        
var x=document.forms["add"]["date1"].value
if ( x=="" || x==null) 
  { 
  alert("Please Enter a time");
  return false
  }  

</script>
```

And here is the corresponding HTML script

```
<form name="add" action="time-sheet/insert-time-sheet.php" method="post" onsubmit="return mandatoryFields()">
<table width="500" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="150">Select Date:</td>
    <td width="336"><input name="date" type="text" value="YYYY-MM-DD" maxlength="100" class="datepick" id="date1" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Contract:</td>
    <td><SELECT NAME="contract_id" onChange="getSprint(this.value)"><OPTION VALUE=0>--- Select Contract ---<?php echo $options_contract?></SELECT></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sprint:</td>
    <td><div id="sprintdiv"><select name="sprint" >
    <option>--- Select Sprint ---</option>
        </select></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Story:</td>
    <td><div id="storydiv"><select name="story">
    <option>--- Select Story ---</option>
        </select></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Dev Time:</td>
    <td><input name="dev_time" size="20" onkeyup="ondalikSayiKontrol(this)" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>PM Time:</td>
    <td><input name="pm_time" size="20" onkeyup="ondalikSayiKontrol(this)"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><table width="182" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
      <tr>

        <td width="68"><input name="Submit" type="submit" id="Submit" value="Add Time Sheet" /></td>
        <td width="48"><label>
          <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset" />
        </label></td>
        <td width="46"><div align="center"><a href="javascript:history.go(-1);">Back</a></div></td>
      </tr>
      <input type="hidden" name="day" value="<?php echo $day; ?>" />
      <input type="hidden" name="employee_id" value="<?php echo $employee_id; ?>" />
    </table></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "doesn't seem to work"??

Comment: validate "HTML script"??u mean validate controls on html page rite?

Comment: Use your browser's javascript console to see the error log and paste it back here.

Comment: u r missing the closing brace.r u getting any error?

Comment: Tried using the brower's javascript console and nothing appears

Comment: Added closing brackets but no sucess

Comment: @user2093306 did you try returning true after the last `if` statement, and removing all of the `var`s except for the first one?

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the closing brace on the function. If you check the error console on your browser, it will most likely tell you `mandatoryFields()` is undefined. Adding the closing brace will fix that. You should also return `true` if none of the validation fails. One last thing is that you re-declare x before each if. Not sure if it produces an error but still should be fixed.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function mandatoryFields()
{
    var x=document.forms["add"]["contract_id"].value;
    if (x==null || x=="")
    {
        alert("Please Enter the Contract Title");
        return false;
    }
    x=document.forms["add"]["storydiv"].value;
    if (x==null || x=="")
    {
        alert("Please Enter a Sprint");
        return false;
    }
    x=document.forms["add"]["storydiv"].value;
    if (x==null || x=="")
    { 
        alert("Please Enter a Story");
        return false;
    }
    x=document.forms["add"]["date1"].value;
    if ( x=="" || x==null) 
    {
        alert("Please Enter a time");
        return false;
    }
    return true; // ADD THIS
} // ADD THIS
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `madatoryFields()` function is not returning **true** when all fields are right.

from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536972%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> If the event handler is called by the onsubmit attribute of the form
>   object, the code must explicitly request the return value using the
>   return function, and the event handler must provide an explicit return
>   value for each possible code path in the event handler function.

Comment: Changes made yet the Javascript still not working on the HTML script

Answer (score 0):

Get the right elements and perform a loop on the options inside of sprint and story.
You can use the name of your form and the names of your select boxes to access the elements straight forward.

```
var x = document.add.contract_id.value;
if(){
 ... your stuff here
}
```

You can also access the first form without using its name attribute.

```
x = document.forms[0].contract_id.value;
```

For sprint loop through possible options and make your alert then.

```
x = document.add.sprint;
var selected = false;
for (i = 0; i < x.length; ++i){
   if (x.options[i].selected == true)
      selected = true;
}
if(!selected){
   alert("Select a story please!");
   return false;
}

x = document.add.story;
selected = false;
// same procedure
```

You can also access the elements via getElementByID() and getElementsByTagName(), the latter returns an array of all matched elements.

```
document.getElementById('storydiv').getElementsByTagName('story')[0];

document.getElementsByTagName('contract_id')[0];
```

And dont redeclare var x in every validation step.